# How to display Progressbar in Android Application Class?

Tags: android, progressdialog

Dear Folks,
             I am running to a difficulty where I am trying to display the `ProgresDialog` from the `Android` class which extends application. I am currently doing

```
context=getApplicationContext();
dialog=ProgressDialog.show(context, "Status", "Downloading The master");
```

But it throws me the following exception

Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Please help me out

Comment: maybe you have to add some coding work to ur question

Comment: You need to use ActivityContext. But why do you require a a progress dialog in a non activity class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getApplicationContext(), just use this.

or class name .this

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 classNAme.this in
```

place of

```
 getApplicationContext().
```

OR

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        //If there are stories, add them to the table
       // do your stub here
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

Just use youractvity.this instead of you context.

```
ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(youractvity.this, "Status", "Downloading The master");
```